# R reading a tsv file using specific encoding

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a .tsv (tab-separated value) file into R using a specific encoding.  It's supposedly `windows-1252`.  And it has a header.

Any suggestions for the code to put it into a data frame?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
mydf <- read.table('thefile.txt', header=TRUE, sep="\t", fileEncoding="windows-1252")
str(mydf)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

`read.delim('thefile.txt', header= T, fileEncoding= "windows-1252")`

Simply entering the command into your R consol:

```
 > read.delim
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", dec = ".", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
```

reveals that `read.delim` is a packaged `read.table` command that already specifies tabs as your data's separator. `read.delim` might be more convenient if you're working with a lot of tsv files.

The difference between the two commands is discussed in more detail [in this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599708/difference-between-read-table-and-read-delim-functions-in-r).

Answer (score 2):

`df <- read.delim(~/file_directory/file_name.tsv, header = TRUE)` will be working fine for single `.tsv` file, because it is already *tab* separated, so no need `sep = "\t"`. `fileEncoding= "windows-1252"` could be used but not necessary.