# R - how to get a word in a specific location from a string?

Tags: r

How can I get a word in a specific location from a string?

For instance I want to get the [station code](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/weatherData/weatherData.pdf) in London, UK:

```
code <- getStationCode("London", region="UNITED KINGDOM")
code
```

Result:

```
[1] "UNITED KINGDOM    EGLINTON/LONDOND EGAE               55 02N  007 09W    9   X     T          6 GB"
[2] "UNITED KINGDOM    LONDON/GATWICK A EGKK        03776  51 08N  000 10W   62   X     T          6 GB"
[3] "UNITED KINGDOM    LONDON CITY AIRP EGLC               51 30N  000 03E    5   X     T          6 GB"
[4] "UNITED KINGDOM    LONDON/HEATHROW  EGLL        03772  51 29N  000 27W   24   X     T          6 GB"
[5] "UNITED KINGDOM    LONDON WEA CENTE EGRB        03779  51 30N  000 07W   39   X                7 GB"
```

For instance I select the second item in the list:

```
second <- code[2]
```

I will get:

```
"UNITED KINGDOM    LONDON/GATWICK A EGKK        03776  51 08N  000 10W   62   X     T          6 GB"
```

Then how can I get `EGKK` from that string?

Comment: It seems the data in each vector is tab-separated. If that's from a file, you should try 'read.table' with tab as a separator e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764470/r-reading-a-tsv-file-using-specific-encoding

If the data is not from a file (e.g. from an API), you can split each string by tab with the `str_split` function in `stringr` i.e. `code <- str_split(code, sep = "\t")`, then select the 3rd element for each item in the resulting list.

Comment: @PhilippeMarchand thanks for spotting that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to extract one or more upper case letters followed by regex lookaround (one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`))

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "[A-Z]+(?=\\s+[0-9]+)")
#[1] "EGKK"
```

If the Station codes are 4 letter strings

```
str_extract(str1, "\\b[A-Z]{4}\\b")
#[1] "EGKK"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "UNITED KINGDOM    LONDON/GATWICK A EGKK        03776  51 08N  000 10W   62   X     T          6 GB"
```

Comment: If the location is truly fixed `substring` may be a quicker solution than regex.

Comment: The first regex pattern works, but the second (`"\\b[A-Z]{4}\\b"`) would get the wrong string when applied to the third row.

Comment: @WeihuangWong  You are right, I didn't check all the rows.